# JavaScript event on Odoo's header button

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to have a JavaScript event fired on a header button (the workflow button).

This is my js

```
var _t = instance.web._t, QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    instance.web.FormView.include({

        init: function() {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        events: {
            "click .resume_consultation": "resume_consultation",
        },

        resume_consultation : function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();

        }

    })
```

The xml for button

```
<header>
    <button type="object" class="resume_consultation"
        name="testonly"
        string="Test Only"/>
</header>
```

The python

```
@api.multi
def testonly(self):
    return False
```

The event is not called. But I know that the `init` from the FormView is executed. It's just that the event is not.

Anyone know how to do it for the workflow buttons?

Comment: Frist check whether your event is getting bind with your element or not.

Answer (score 0):

first of all add your js file following code :

```
odoo.define('Modulename.filename', function (require) {
"use strict";

var form_widget = require('web.form_widgets');
var core = require('web.core');
var _t = core._t;
var QWeb = core.qweb;

form_widget.WidgetButton.include({
    on_click: function() {
         if(this.node.attrs.custom === "click"){
            //code//
         }
         this._super();
    },
});
});
```

after this add your js file in xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <odoo>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="project assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                         <script type="text/javascript" src="/product_pack/static/src/js/product_pack.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template> </odoo>
```

ather that define your click event function in your py file

```
class SalePetOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "xyz"

    def java_script(self):
        return {"hello": "world"}
```

after define your function in your xml :

```
<data>
   <header>
    <button name="java_script" string="Java Script" type="object" custom="click"/>
   </header>
</data>
```

and yes define your js file and xml file in your **manifest** /*openerp* file .

I hope it helps you.

Comment: From your javascript Im guessing this is for odoo 10? Because odoo 8 are still using openerp as the identifier name.